# Update Inventory table using INNER JOIN sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to update my Inventory table using INNER JOIN

what need to be done is get [JoinedTable.NumOrder] with current time.

tables :

```
Inventory(ProductID, ProductName, price, OnHand)

Orders(OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID)

OrderLine(OrderID, ProductID, NumOrdered)

UPDATE Inventory
INNER JOIN (SELECT OrderLine.ProductID, SUM(OrderLine.NumOrdered) AS NumOrdered
FROM Orders, OrderLine
WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID
AND Orders.OrderDate = Date()
GROUP BY OrderLine.ProductID) AS Add
ON Inventory.ProductID = Add.ProductID
SET Inventory.OnHand  = Inventory.OnHand + Add.NumOrdered
;
```

this query gives Operation must use an updateable query error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.

```
UPDATE Inventory
SET Inventory.OnHand  = Inventory.OnHand + Add.NumOrdered
FROM INVENTORY
INNER JOIN (SELECT OrderLine.ProductID, SUM(OrderLine.NumOrdered) AS NumOrdered
FROM Orders, OrderLine
WHERE Orders.OrderID = OrderLine.OrderID
AND Orders.OrderDate = Date()
GROUP BY OrderLine.ProductID) AS Add
ON Inventory.ProductID = Add.ProductID;
```